# Como limpiar resultados de un Tag HTML? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una función que cuando toco un botón html llama a una función `javascript` para imprimir los resultados en una tabla ya creada pero vacía, que en este caso se llama "tablaElegida". Como podría hacer para que cuando vuelva a tocar desaparezca. entiendo lo del evento onclick y el remove child pero me vuelvo loco con javascript porque el frontend no es mi fuerte.

Olvidé mencionar que ya termino todo el proyecto sin jquery, si es posible seguiré asi, sino veré como lo implemento.

```
function verEventos(){

var usuario= document.getElementById("usuario");
var pass= document.getElementById("pass");

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url= "/Proyecto_Final_AAB/rest/adminSeg/verEventos";

if(usuario=="" && pass==""){

    alert("Los campos 'usuario' y 'pass' no pueden quedar en blanco.")

    }
else
    {

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= function(){
            if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){


        //Creación de títulos
        //Elegimos el elemento donde Totos los 'td' van a ser adheridos
        var tablaElegida= document.getElementById("tablaElegida");

        var cabecera = ["-ID-", "nombre", "Fecha"];

        for( var i=0; i < cabecera.length; i++)
        {
                var tablaElegida= document.getElementById("tablaElegida");

                var crearTitulos=document.createElement("td");

                var textoNombre= document.createTextNode(cabecera[i]);

                crearTitulos.appendChild(textoNombre);

                tablaElegida.appendChild(crearTitulos).style.border = "solid yellow";
        }


                //Esta es la respuesta del servidor, sobre esta recaen todas las acciones.
                var datos= xmlhttp.responseText;

                //Parseamos los datos
                var parseDatos= JSON.parse(datos);


                //Iteramos sobre la respuesta del JSON
                for(var i=0; i < xmlhttp.responseText.length; i++){


                    //Creamos un renglon por cada elemento que iteramos
                        var hilera= document.createElement("tr");
                        var tablaElegida= document.getElementById("tablaElegida");
                            tablaElegida.appendChild(hilera);


                    //id_evento
                        //Creamos los td  que contendrán los resultados
                        var newtdId_evento= document.createElement("td");

                        //Adherimos los td a la tabla ya existente
                        tablaElegida.appendChild(newtdId_evento).style.border = "thin solid white";

                        //Creamos el texto y aherimos las columnas parseadas
                        var textoId_evento= document.createTextNode(parseDatos[i].id_evento);

                        //Adherimos el texto ya creado a los td
                        newtdId_evento.appendChild(textoId_evento);


                    //Nombre
                        //Creamos los td  que contendrán los resultados
                        var newtdNombre= document.createElement("td");

                        //Adherimos los td a la tabla ya existente
                        tablaElegida.appendChild(newtdNombre).style.border = "thin solid white";

                        //Creamos el texto y aherimos las columnas parseadas
                        var textoNombre= document.createTextNode(parseDatos[i].nombre);

                        //Adherimos el texto ya creado a los td
                        newtdNombre.appendChild(textoNombre);   


                    //Fecha
                        //Creamos los td  que contendrán los resultados
                        var newtdFecha= document.createElement("td");

                        //Adherimos los td a la tabla ya existente
                        tablaElegida.appendChild(newtdFecha).style.border = "thin solid white";

                        //Creamos el texto y aherimos las columnas parseadas
                        var textoFecha= document.createTextNode(parseDatos[i].fecha);

                        //Adherimos el texto ya creado a los td
                        newtdFecha.appendChild(textoFecha);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("usuario="+usuario.value+"&pass="+pass.value);
}
```

Y este es el html, una parte únicamente porque es largo:

```
<div id="resultados">
        <ul id="ulElegido">
            <table id="tablaElegida"></table>
        </ul>

</div>
```

acá el botón:

```
<table id="verTodosEventos">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Ver eventos" onclick="verEventos()">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Había pensado en cambiar el appendChild al ul que está creado y después removeChild, pero bueno escucho si hay soluciones más eficientes.

Comment: ¿Puedes usar jQuery? Prueba hacer `$('#tablaElegida').empty()`

Comment: @Lixus ya lo estoy terminando el proyecto en javascript puro, si no no hay otra lo usaré.

Comment: En caso de que no puedas, esta respuesta es lo que buscas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript

Comment: gracias @Lixus, estoy viendo de implementar tu respuesta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usa algún método para seleccionar el elemento, como `getElementById` y luego `innerHTML`.

Ejemplo:

```js
var resultados = document.getElementById('resultados');
var contenido = "Ponga aquí el contenido a agregar";

function llenar(){
  resultados.innerHTML = contenido;
}

function vaciar(){
  resultados.innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="llenar()">Llenar</button>
&nbsp;
<button onclick="vaciar()">Vaciar</button>
<div id="resultados"><div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para vaciar un contenido en un `tag` puedes ocupar la funcion `.innerHTML` en javascript, o bien `.empty()` en jquery.

**HTML**

```
<div id="resultados">
        <ul id="ulElegido">
            <table id="tablaElegida"></table>
        </ul>
</div>
```

**Ejemplo Javascript**

```
function vaciar(){
  document.getElementById('resultados').innerHTML = '';
}
```

**Ejemplo Jquery**

```
function vaciar(){
  $('#resultados').empty();
}
```

Espero que pueda ser de ayuda :D

Ejemplo completo:

```js
//JavaScript
function vaciar(){
  document.getElementById('resultados').innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->
<div id="resultados">
    <ul id="ulElegido">
      <table id="tablaElegida" border="1">
        <tr>
          <td>Campo1</td>
          <td>Campo2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Campo3</td>
          <td>Campo4</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <button onclick="vaciar()">Vaciar</button>
</div>
```